# Flutter ~ How to call a method once when back from any other page?

Tags: flutter

In my home screen, I am displaying a count by reading from a JSON file by calling a method, getCount().

The file is updated from any page of the application.

For the first time the app is loaded, I can call the getCount() from initState() and I am able to get the value of getCount().

If I navigate to any other page and back to the home screen, I can call the getCount() method from inside build method, which works but I find that it keeps on calling the getCount() method infinite number of times.

I think there would be clean way to handle this scenario. I am new to the land of flutter, please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change your logic. Everytime you refresh your JSON, automatically update a global variable with that value (or in other words, put your method logic right under your logic for updating your JSON). Then simply access it wherever you need it.